# Monitoring Power Down Using Arduino UNO and ZMPT101B

Tags: arduino

I am in the process of implementing power down alerting system suing Arduino UNO and ZMPT101B Single phase relay.

My code as follows,

```cpp
#include <Filters.h> //Easy library to do the calculations

float testFrequency = 50;                     // test signal frequency (Hz)
float windowLength = 40.0/testFrequency;     // how long to average the signal, for statistist

int Sensor = 0; //Sensor analog input, here it's A0

float intercept = -0.04; // to be adjusted based on calibration testing
float slope = 0.0405; // to be adjusted based on calibration testing
float current_Volts; // Voltage

unsigned long printPeriod = 1000; //Refresh rate
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin( 9600 );    // start the serial port
}

void loop() {

    RunningStatistics inputStats;                //Easy life lines, actual calculation of the RMS requires a load of coding
    inputStats.setWindowSecs( windowLength );

    while( true ) {   
        Sensor = analogRead(A0);  // read the analog in value:
        inputStats.input(Sensor);  // log to Stats function

        if((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillis) >= printPeriod) {
            previousMillis = millis();   // update time every second

            Serial.print( "\n" );

            current_Volts = intercept + slope * inputStats.sigma(); //Calibartions for offset and amplitude
            current_Volts= current_Volts*(40.3231);                //Further calibrations for the amplitude

            Serial.print( "\tVoltage: " );
            Serial.print( current_Volts ); //Calculation and Value display is done the rest is if you're using an OLED display

            if (current_Volts <229) {
                test_loop();
            }
        }
    }
}

void test_loop(){
    Serial.print( "Warning!! Server Room Power Down" );
    delay(1000);
}
```

I am getting the correct voltage reading. 
But when power down it says power down. 
But when power got up it still shows power down with older reading. 
I think the reason for this because my code unable to stop the loop. 
And if I remove the delay (1000) in test_loop function it works, 
But my intention to use this sms alerting system and for that I need this delay to stop unnecessary alerts.

My code for SMS Alerting,

```cpp
Serial.print( "\tVoltage: " );
Serial.print( current_Volts ); //Calculation and Value display is done the rest is if you're using an OLED display

if (current_Volts <229) {
    SendMessage();
}

void test_loop() {
    mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    //Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
    delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
    mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"xxxxxxxxx\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number
    delay(1000);
    mySerial.println("Warning!! Server Room Power Down");
    delay(100);
    mySerial.println((char)26);// ASCII code of CTRL+Z
    delay(150000);
    mySerial.println("AT+CMGD=2");
}
```

This code works for the very first outage but after power up also it send power down. 
First code of Serial.print is used fro debugging.

Kindly help.

Comment: Using `delay` inside `test_loop` doesn't do any problem. Which value do you get for `current_Volts` after power down ends? Do you get values higher than `229`? Also, why you use a smart delay in your loop?

Comment: Thanks for reply. While power down it shows lower value but when power back on it still shows a lower value.I ma suspecting older values shows. I need this delay to be checked the GSM Module to be sending a SMS. Without delay GSM Module will not function and will send 1000 of SMS for 1 second power down.

Comment: Your logic seems fine and I think your problem is with the Filter. Try to add a print statement for `Sensor` and check if the value changes.

Comment: If I print the sensor output the value will not be RMS. Since it's analog output I am afraid the value will be useless.

Comment: I know but I'm saying maybe the filter you are using is the problem, print the value and check if it raises when the Sensor gets high.

Comment: It's still same, please see the video : https://www.dropbox.com/s/npnjdxgo0c8ocz2/ice_video_20190813-111052.mp4?dl=0 I have only turned off the power for 1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the Arduino Forum User: leongjerland

I was able to fix the issue. 
The code as below,

```
if (current_Volts < 229) {
        if (!alarmSent) {
          test_loop();
          alarmSent = true;
        }
      }
      else {
        alarmSent = false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing with a voltmeter what the voltage is at the A0 pin in the good and the bad case. You don't need to decode the voltage, just see if it the sensor is working as you expect.